# How to test if one rect is in another rect?

Tags: c#, java, c++, collision-detection

Alright, so I'm working on a game and I have found out that my enemies don't like my collision detection that works perfectly for my player. After a little debugging I found out it's because my enemies are bigger than my tiles, while my player is smaller than my tiles.

Now I need to be able to make big enemies and bosses, so this just won't do. so I need to figure out a better way to test collision detection. This is how I am currently doing it:

up and down:

```
if((enemy.left > tile.left && enemy.left < tile.right || enemy.right > tile.left && enemy.right < tile.right) && enemy.top < tile.bottom && enemy.bottom > tile.top){
    //collision
}
```

left and right:

```
if((enemy.top > tile.top && enemy.top < tile.bottom || enemy.bottom > tile.top && enemy.bottom < tile.bottom) && enemy.left < tile.right && enemy.right > tile.left){
     //colision
}
```

Comment: Is your sprite purely rectangular?

Comment: it's 52x32, and tiles are 50x50

Comment: I mean, for most games, collision detection of sprites is not simply detecting overlapping rectangles, for example, if both your enemy and your avatar are circular, the are not essentially crashed even the rectangles are overlapped.

Comment: There are quite a few answers below so I will just add in a comment. You want to aim for Early Out collision detection. In order to do this you actually want to check values of when you can't possibly be colliding and just return False from your checks. For example, if (object1.bot < object2.top) return false; (the bottom is no where near the top so this is a false). Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, use [`intersects(Rectangle r)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Comment: +1, since this is the option I'd go for.  If I had to write my own custom code, I'd make my public interface look like this, anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to correctly do the separating axis tests (for oriented bounding boxes, like you're doing).

```
if (firstObject.Left < secondObject.Right && firstObject.Right > secondObject.Left
    && firstObject.Top < secondObject.Bottom && firstObject.Bottom > secondObject.Top)
{
    // Intersecting
}
```

Go to this site, and play with Figure 3, making all of these true one at a time.  Then break each of the tests, one at a time.  You'll see empirically that it works, and is about as simple as you can get:

http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html#section1

If you feel like it, read through the whole set of tutorials.  It'll be worth it once you start packing more features into your game :)

Answer (score 2):

In .NET languages, you can use the `Rectangle.IntersectsWith(Rectangle other)` method to perform very basic collision detection.

Comment: Oh, well thank you but I kinda figured the answer would be more...portable. Still, as I code in C# as well as C++ and Java I found your answer useful enough to upvote, but it's not what I'm looking for. 
Edit: a non-portable answer in Java is fine however, as that's what my game is coded in.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone working in Objective-C looking for the same answer you can use:

```
bool CGRectIntersectsRect(CGRect rect1, CGRect rect2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in

```
enemy.top < tile.bottom && enemy.bottom > tile.top
```

(In first code), this will only be true if enemy is within the tile fully (height-wise)

```
enemy.top > tile.top && enemy.top < tile.bottom || enemy.bottom > tile.top && enemy.bottom < tile.bottom
```

Like you have done with the left + right check.

Just to clarify this would mean the first check you gave would be:

```
if((enemy.left > tile.left && enemy.left < tile.right || enemy.right > tile.left && enemy.right < tile.right) && (enemy.top > tile.top && enemy.top < tile.bottom || enemy.bottom > tile.top && enemy.bottom < tile.bottom)){
//collision
```

}

And with this I dont think you would need seperate up/down left/right checks, this should return true if ANY part of enemy is within tile

Comment: You really only need about half the tests you're doing in your final answer.  Check my answer for a more efficient set of tests.

Comment: Oh yeah, thats a much better way.

Answer (score 0):

The sprite is wider than the tile, but the "left-right" code doesn't check for that case.
If i graph your code, it simply checks whether the enemy left or the enemy right lies within the tile:

```
(enemy.left > tile.left && enemy.left < tile.right
|| enemy.right > tile.left && enemy.right < tile.right)

// graphed as<br>
// TL EL TR ----- or ----- TL ER TR<br>
```

but if the entire tile lies within the enemy region, no hit is detected:

```
//  EL TL ----- and ----- TR ER
```

Similarly, the Tile is smaller vertially than the enemy, so it is necessary to check the if the entire tile lies within the enemy.
The complete graph/pseudo code is:

```
 is_hit :
 // T{L,R,T,B} => tile, E{L,R,T,B} => enemy
 // left-right:
 [
  TL EL TR ----- or ----- TL ER TR
           . or .
  EL TL ----- and ----- TR ER
 ]
 .and.
 // top-bottom:
 [
  TT ET TB ----- or ----- TT EB TB
           . or .
  ET TT ----- and ----- TB EB
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `.Net` there is already a method named `Intersect(Rect rect)` in `Rect` class.